# How do I solve Cannot access 'email' before initialization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am still new to MERN stack development. I have a http://localhost:8000/api/signin endpoint where the email and password is submitted. The backend code first checks if a user is already saved in MongoDB then the password submitted in the endpoint will be compared with the one saved in the database(mongodb).

**/controllers/auth.js**

```
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const signInUser = async () => {
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      let findUser = await User.findOne({ email }); // promise is the new way of doing this instead of callback as of express 4.18 and mongoose 7.0.3

      console.log('findUser', findUser);

      if (!findUser) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: 'User with that email does not exist. Please signup'
        })
      }

      // authenticate
      if (!findUser.authenticate(password)) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: 'Email and password do not match'
        })
      }

      // generate a token and send to client
      const token = jwt.sign({_id: findUser._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' });
      const {_id, name, email, role} = existingUser;

     return res.json({
      message: 'Yey!'
     })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error); // Sometimes this error is not displayed on postman

      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Something went wrong'
      })
    }
  }

  signInUser();
};
```

Problem: I am currently seeing a `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'email' before initialization` error. I think the error starts on line `const {_id, name, email, role} = existingUser;`

Do you have any idea how can I update my code to overcome the error?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @cmgchess `existingUser` is a new variable. From what I understood, `const {_id, name, email, role} = existingUser` is called desctructuring.

Comment: but then existingUser is undefined. are you getting it from a db or something

Comment: @cmgchess Actually, I am following a tutorial. The old code was using callbacks and it will cause errors with today's version of packages. I then converted the code into async await,  The `existingUser` variable should be `user` variable. The equivalent of ` `let findUser = await User.findOne({ email });` in the original code is `User.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {}`

Comment: The user data from db is in `findUser` variable.

Comment: try `const {_id, name, role} = findUser;`. I removed email since you have it already. By the way why do you have that line? It has no usage.

Comment: also if you are going to destructure email as well the line `let findUser = await User.findOne({ email });` may break

Comment: Hello @SuleymanSah I will be needing `email` because I will do `return res.json({ token, findUser: { _id, name, email, role } });` in the final return statement.

Comment: @redshot i think whta he meant is you have email already since you are finding by email

Comment: @cmgchess You're right. I am getting the correct output now. Can you write your comment answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Can you write your comment as answer? My code is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`existingUser` is not defined and you are trying to destructure it. Instead you have to destructure the `findUser` which you have obtained above

```js
const {_id, name, role} = findUser;
```

also don't destructure the `email` since you already have it above where you used it to find from the database. If you do it this might break the line `let findUser = await User.findOne({ email });` since you are trying to access the `email` before initialization inside the function (initialization is the destructuring in this case `const {_id, name, email, role} = findUser`.

if you really need to destructure the email you can do something like

```js
{_id, name, email: emailFromDb, role} = findUser.
```

and now you can use the `emailFromDb` from there onwards

Comment: Thank you for your effort in providing the correct code. It worked!